# Variable namespace is not defined. Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, namespaces

i get the following error when trying to use function loadWSDL():

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable namespace is not defined.
    at mx.rpc.xml::SchemaLoader/schemaImports()
    at mx.rpc.wsdl::WSDLLoader/schemaImports()
    at mx.rpc.wsdl::WSDLLoader/resultHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at HTTPOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()
    at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Code:

```
var url = "ServiceURL.svc?wsdl";
        webService = new WebService();
        webService.wsdl = url;
        webService.loadWSDL();
        webService.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD, BuildServiceRequest);
```

How to fix this? When using another webservice - everything works fine, but with this one i get error.

Comment: is `BuildServiceRequest` method placed in the same scope?

Comment: Yes it is. Ir worked out after i changed wsdl url to .svc?SingleWsdl but it should also work with the standart ?wsdl, i think

Comment: interesting.. try to escape the question mark with the "\" , like `"ServiceURL.svc\?wsdl"`

Comment: I get error at opening the service. I think i will be using SingleWsdl as 'wsdl' doesn't work. Of course would be interesting to find the answer why